# Watson Discovery Service Issue

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, discovery, watson-discovery

[Right Way - It's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPWts.png) 
[Wrong Way - Isn't working how should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqD3t.png)
I'd like your help about an issue. I'm using wds and so I created a collection that was uploaded by several pieces of a manual. Once I did it, on the conversation service I also created, I put some descriptions on the intentions that the Discovery should uses. Now, when I try to identify these descriptions on the Discovery Service, unless I write exactly the same to test, it's not recognizing. Any suggestion about what can I use to fix it?

e.g. I uploaded a metadata txt file with the following fields:

```
+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
|      Document       | DocumentID |   Chapter   |       Session         |  Title  | Page |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
| Instructions Manual | BR_1       | Maintenance | Long Period of Disuse | Chassis |  237 |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
```

Now, when I search on the Discovery, I need to use the exactly word I put on the intention's description (Chassis). Otherwise the Discovery it's not getting through the way below:

> metadata.Title:chas*|metadata.Chapter:chas*|metadata.Session:chas*

Any idea??

Comment: Have you created a custom configuration for the collection or else are you using default configuration?. And, could be please clear about the issue like what you trying to do and what is the output and what are you expecting screenshots might be helpful

Comment: I'm using the defalut configuration. For example, the query `metadata.Title:chas*|metadata.Chapter:chas*|metadata.Session:chas*`, works when I search for the document I uploaded on Discovery, but the same doesn't works when I try to look up for other cases, like: `metadata.Title:emergen*|metadata.Chapter:emergen*|metadata.Session:emergen*`.
Just to explain, I'm looking for documents about a car I uploaded on the Discovery. The first one was about the Chassis part of the car, and the second about an emergency topic of the car's manual. Did you understand my problem?

Comment: does any your metadata fields contain emergency topic ( text emergency)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the syntax if its right or wrong by matching it with discovery tool.
Sometimes we need inverted commas with backslash.